Genus of binary quadratic forms: $f(x,y), g(x,y)$ in same genus if and only if represent same values in $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\ast$ for all $m$
In David Cox's book: Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$, second edition, there is a theorem(Theorem 3.21, page 52) characterize whether two binary quadratic forms in the same genus. The contents of the theorem are:
Let $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ be primitive forms of discriminant $D\neq0$, positive definite if $D<0$. Then the following are equivalent:
(i) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are in the same genus, i.e., they represent the same values in $(\mathbb Z/D\mathbb Z)^\ast$.
(ii) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ represent the same values in $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\ast$ for all nonzero integer $m$.
(iii) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equivalent modulo $m$ for all nonzero integer $m$.
(iv) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equivalent over the $p$-adic integer $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all primes $p$.
(v) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equivalent over $\mathbb Q$ via a matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb Q)$ whose entries have denominators prime to $2D$.
(vi) $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are equivalent over $\mathbb Q$ without essential denominators, i.e., given any nonzero $m$, a matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb Q)$ can be found which takes one form to the other and whose entries have denominators prime to $m$.
The author does not give details of the proof, only some references.
Question: How to derive (ii) and (iii) from (i), and how to prove the equivalence of (iv) and (vi). Could someone please give me some hints？
Addition: $x^2+14y^2$ and $2x^2+7y^2$ are in the same genus, and for primes $p\neq 2,7$,
$$p=x^2+14y^2\,\text{or}\,2x^2+7y^2\Leftrightarrow p\equiv1,9,15,23,25,39\pmod {56}.$$
Is it right that for every congruent class of $1,9,15,23,25,39\pmod {56}$, both $x^2+14y^2$ and $2x^2+7y^2$ represent infinitely many prime numbers in the class?

Yes; in the first edition, Theorem 9.12  on page 188  that the Dirichlet density of represented primes exists. Further more, if the form is "ambiguous,"   such as your $x^2 + 14 y^2$   or your $2 x^2 + 7 y^2,$  the density is $\frac{1}{2 h(D)}.$  Let's see, you also want primes in a specific arithmetic progression. The answer is yes, but I'm not sure of a place in this book.

@WillJagy Blair K. Spearman and Kenneth S. Williams shown that every such arithmetic progression either contains no primes of the form $x^2 + 14y^2$ or it contains primes of both forms$ x^2 + 14y^2$ and $2x^2 + 7y^2$ in the paper: Representing Primes by Binary Quadratic Forms,The American Mathematical Monthly , May, 1992, Vol. 99, No. 5 (May, 1992), pp. 423-426. I also think the both represent infinitely many prime numbers in each congruent class but I don't know how to prove.

@WillJagy  Lemmermeyer in this MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144544/primes-represented-by-an-indefinite-binary-quadratic-form said that“Meyer (Über einen Satz von Dirichlet, Crelle 103 (1888)) proved that a primitive binary quadratic form with nonsquare discriminant represents infinitely many primes that lie in any given compatible residue class modulo a given integer N”。 Unfortunately, I don't know German。
